# Random Forest Classifier Python: ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest, valueerror

I've used Random Forest many times but have never encountered this error:
    ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

My train_x dataframe is in this format:

[image: Dataframe]

How would I change the format, so I can run my classifiers?

I thought the issue was that tfidf and lda were given as matrices, but I already converted these values to lists, which did not help.

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
clf2 = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=1)
clf2.fit(train_x, train_y)
```

Full Error below:

---

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-111-7ae6360c296b> in <module>()
----> 1 clf2.fit(train_x, train_y)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\forest.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    245         """
    246         # Validate or convert input data
--> 247         X = check_array(X, accept_sparse="csc", dtype=DTYPE)
    248         y = check_array(y, accept_sparse='csc', ensure_2d=False, dtype=None)
    249         if sample_weight is not None:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    431                                       force_all_finite)
    432     else:
--> 433         array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)
    434 
    435         if ensure_2d:

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Comment: Scikit doesnt handle 2-d arrays inside a column as you are doing here in `X_train`. You need to make a simple 2-d array by combining the rows.

Comment: Hi Vivek, I'm not sure what you mean. You are saying I should make a different 2d-array out of an existing 2d-array? How exactly are those 2d arrays different?